# grails placeholder not resolved in external configuration file when running from war

Tags: grails, configuration, properties

In my grails app (grails 1.3.7), my `Config.groovy` adds some additional external locations using `grails.config.locations`. One of the external location is a properties file that uses a property placeholer, e.g.

```
myprop=${base.dir}/some/other/stuff
```

This works when running `grails run-app`, but when I deploy to a war, I get an error saying `Could not resolve placeholder 'base.dir'`.

Any thoughts as to why this would run in dev mode but not from a war?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you do this:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=myenv war myfile.war
```

Then deploy to your app container in myenv and get base.dir issue..

Try to manually set base.dir in Config.groovy

```
environments {
    myenv {
        base.dir = 'expected/base/dir'
    }
}
```

hope this helps..

Comment: base.dir is a grails property from the BuildSettings http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/api/grails/util/BuildSettings.html